# Spreadsheet program where I can paste image and it belongs to a cell?

Tags: images, spreadsheet, copy-paste

In Miscrosoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc when I paste image from clipboard, it is appearing above the cells, not belonging to any of them. I need that image data was belong to a single cell I pasted it to.

Are the any spreadheet software with this ability anywhere?